# Flutter - Password check not updating

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a flutter application. I listed the requirements for the password on the registration page in the app. As the user types his password, I want to instantly listen to whether these requirements are met and update the text. First of all, my codes are as follows:

`register_view.dart`:

```
class RegisterView extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterView({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterView> createState() => _RegisterViewState();
}

class _RegisterViewState extends State<RegisterView> with RegisterViewMixin {
  final RegisterViewModel _viewModel = RegisterViewModel();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScaffold(
      onPadding: true,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            const ToggLogoWidget(width: TextSizeEnum.xxlarge),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            const CustomText(
              text: "Tru.ID hesabınızı oluşturun",
              color: AppColors.skyBlueText,
              fontSize: TextSizeEnum.medium,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            CustomTextFormField(
              hintText: "İsim",
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'İsim boş bırakılamaz';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            _buildSizedBox(),
            CustomTextFormField(
              hintText: "Soyisim",
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Soyisim boş bırakılamaz';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            _buildSizedBox(),
            CustomTextFormField(
              hintText: "E-Posta",
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'E-Posta adresi boş bırakılamaz';
                } else if (!StringUtil.isValidEmail(value)) {
                  return 'Geçerli bir e-posta adresi giriniz';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 6),
            const CustomText(
              icon: Icon(Icons.info, color: AppColors.grey),
              text: "Togg bu e-posta adresine bir doğrulama gönderecektir.",
              fontSize: TextSizeEnum.verySmall,
            ),
            _buildSizedBox(),
            CustomTextFormField(
              controller: _viewModel.passwordController,
              hintText: "Şifre",
              obscureText: true,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Şifre boş bırakılamaz';
                } else if (!StringUtil.isPassword8Chars(value)) {
                  return '';
                } else if (!StringUtil.hasNumber(value)) {
                  return '';
                } else if (!StringUtil.hasUpper(value)) {
                  return '';
                } else if (!StringUtil.hasLower(value)) {
                  return '';
                } else if (!StringUtil.hasSpecialCharacter(value)) {
                  return '';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            PasswordValidationWidget(
              password: _viewModel.passwordController.text,
              confirmPassword: _viewModel.confirmPasswordController.text,
            ),
            _buildSizedBox(),
            CustomTextFormField(
              controller: _viewModel.confirmPasswordController,
              hintText: "Şifre Yeniden",
              obscureText: true,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Şifre boş bırakılamaz';
                } else if (!StringUtil.isPassword8Chars(value)) {
                  return '';
                } else if (!StringUtil.hasNumber(value)) {
                  return '';
                } else if (!StringUtil.hasUpper(value)) {
                  return '';
                } else if (!StringUtil.hasLower(value)) {
                  return '';
                } else if (!StringUtil.hasSpecialCharacter(value)) {
                  return '';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            _buildSizedBox(),
            CustomDarkButton(
              text: "Hesap Oluştur",
              active: true,
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  //basarili
                } else {
                  // basarisiz
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  PreferredSizeWidget _buildAppBar() {
    return const WelcomeAppBar();
  }

  SizedBox _buildSizedBox() {
    return const SizedBox(height: 20);
  }
}
```

`password_validation_widget.dart`:

```
class PasswordValidationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String password;
  final String confirmPassword;

  const PasswordValidationWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.password,
    required this.confirmPassword,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PasswordValidationWidget> createState() => _PasswordValidationWidgetState();
}

class _PasswordValidationWidgetState extends State<PasswordValidationWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        _buildValidationRow("En az 8 karakter uzunluğunda", StringUtil.isPassword8Chars(widget.password)),
        _buildValidationRow("En az 1 özel karakter içermeli", StringUtil.hasSpecialCharacter(widget.password)),
        _buildValidationRow("En az 1 sayı içermeli", StringUtil.hasNumber(widget.password)),
        _buildValidationRow("En az 1 büyük harf içermeli", StringUtil.hasUpper(widget.password)),
        _buildValidationRow("En az 1 küçük harf içermeli", StringUtil.hasLower(widget.password)),
        _buildValidationRow("Şifreler eşleşmeli", StringUtil.arePasswordsMatching(widget.password, widget.confirmPassword)),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildValidationRow(String text, bool isValid) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Icon(
          isValid ? Icons.check : Icons.close,
          color: isValid ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 8),
        Text(text),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

`strings_util.dart`:

```
class StringUtil {
  static bool isPassword8Chars(String password) => password.length >= 8;

  static bool hasSpecialCharacter(String password) => password.contains(RegExp(r'[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]'));

  static bool hasNumber(String password) => password.contains(RegExp(r'\d'));

  static bool hasUpper(String password) => password.contains(RegExp(r'[A-Z]'));

  static bool hasLower(String password) => password.contains(RegExp(r'[a-z]'));

  static bool arePasswordsMatching(String password, String confirmPassword) => confirmPassword == password;
}
```

`register_view_model.dart`:

```
class RegisterViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController confirmPasswordController =
      TextEditingController();
}
```

`register_view_mixin.dart`:

```
mixin RegisterViewMixin on State<RegisterView> {
  final RegisterViewModel _viewModel = RegisterViewModel();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _viewModel.passwordController.addListener(_updatePasswordValidation);
    _viewModel.confirmPasswordController.addListener(_updatePasswordValidation);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _viewModel.passwordController.removeListener(_updatePasswordValidation);
    _viewModel.confirmPasswordController.removeListener(_updatePasswordValidation);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updatePasswordValidation() {
    print("test"); // not working
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

When I transferred the codes from the mixin side to the view side, I was able to achieve what I wanted, but I want these codes to remain in the mixin.